# Measuring the effect of adding a feature descriptor?

Tags: self-study, feature-engineering

I have a class A that is often classified as class B. I use Local Binary Patterns in conjunction with a SVM. If I concatenate a color histogram to a standard Local Binary Pattern, it increases it's performance and I don't see class A being miss classified as class B that frequently anymore.

How can I see the effect of this color histogram? For example, can I measure the average distance between Class A and Class B?

I expect it to increase. Would this be a valid argument in a paper to show that the effect of adding a color histogram is that it adds unique information that enables a classifier to distinguish between the two?

In some sense, my question is, what is the measure of distinguishability between two classes?